# Networking event rotation

Tags: combinatorics

In need of a little more math brain power. I am hosting an event where I ultimately want folks to meet new people every time we rotate and not be with the same person twice.

My problem is not having people stay at the same table while rotating. I can get 36 people in groups of 6 to rotate 3 times and never meet the same person, but some of the people never leave their original table or they come back to a table they have already been at. Each table has a different theme and game to play and I don't want people to play a game twice either.

I figure I need to either subtract the number of people or add more tables/games, but can't figure this out.

Comment: could you add a little more background/setup to the problem? i.e. how many people there are, how many tables, etc.. you're trying to set it up so that everybody only meets new people, but also doesn't visit the same table twice so as they don't play the same game twice, is this correct?

Comment: These kinds of problems can be more difficult than one might expect.  Here is a way to incorporate "different tables" into your requirements: treat each table as one of the "people" and begin with a seating that puts all the tables together in a group.  You can find a lot about block designs at [the La Jolla Covering Repository](https://www.ccrwest.org/cover.html).  I'll post an Answer for your specific case.

Comment: i can choose how ever many people i want, ranging between 24-42 would like groups if possible of 4 or 6 at each table. i have either 5 or 6 different stations and want folks to rotate 3 times.  Racking my brain on this one.

Comment: Dando yes exactly what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to show that with $36$ people seated at six tables of six places each, there's no way to reseat everybody to a different table each time without pairing some of the same folks a second time.  Consider the six people at the first table during the first seating.  Where will they go for their second seating?  If they must all go to different tables, one of them would have to remain at that first table (pigeonhole principle).

One idea I'm willing to propose involves $35$ people seated at seven tables of five places each.  In this scheme we could have (up to) six rotated seatings, with no pair of people meeting more than once, and no person seated at the same table more than once.  I note, however, that your preference was to have an even number ($4$ or $6$) of people at each table.  What do you think about the proposed type of scheme?

**28 People (Seven Tables of Four Each, Three Rounds without Repeats)**

Given the desirability of an even number of people at tables (so that games which require a pair of teammates are conducted), I looked for a solution with seven tables and four people at each table (per round).  Here's what I found:

**First Round**

```
Table 1:  A1,B1,C1,D1
Table 2:  A2,B2,C2,D2
Table 3:  A3,B3,C3,D3
Table 4:  A4,B4,C4,D4
Table 5:  A5,B5,C5,D5
Table 6:  A6,B6,C6,D6
Table 7:  A7,B7,C7,D7
```

**Second Round**

```
Table 1:  A2,B3,C4,D5
Table 2:  A3,B4,C5,D6
Table 3:  A4,B5,C6,D7
Table 4:  A5,B6,C7,D1
Table 5:  A6,B7,C1,D2
Table 6:  A7,B1,C2,D3
Table 7:  A1,B2,C3,D4
```

**Third Round**

```
Table 1:  A3,B5,C7,D2
Table 2:  A4,B6,C1,D3
Table 3:  A5,B7,C2,D4
Table 4:  A6,B1,C3,D5
Table 5:  A7,B2,C4,D6
Table 6:  A1,B3,C5,D7
Table 7:  A2,B4,C6,D1
```

It is fairly easy to verify that all twenty-eight people are seated in each round, and that the three seatings at each table are free of repeats.  Less easy to spot is whether there are any pairs of people who meet more than once.  The design is based on a rotation of a certain kind, so that it actually suffices to check any one person (for duplicate meetings) to be sure that no one meets the same person twice.  Here are the seatings for `A1` (and you can see there are no repetitions):

```
Round 1:   A1,B1,C1,D1   (Table 1)
Round 2:   A1,B2,C3,D4   (Table 7)
Round 3:   A1,B3,C5,D7   (Table 6)
```

It follows that each participant will meet nine other people during this networking event.

Comment: Yes that could work. Also thought about doing 2 rounds were people move to a new table and then for the 3rd round have everyone do the same 3rd round which is ultimately a 7th station but that 7th station doesn't show up until the 3rd round and then everyone still rotates and never meets the same person twice but also goes to 3 different stations.

Comment: Even with two rounds, if the number of stations/tables is equal to (or less than) the number of people at each table, then one person at each table has to stay there.  So perhaps we could have seven tables with six at each table, or six tables with five people each.

Comment: I think the way i was playing the numbers last night was based on something you said earlier and have the tables as people so this would be 6 stations with 5 people at each station. So it was a six by six but one set of people really aren't people. The hard part is some of these stations are games for people to play and they are teams of 2. That is why the even numbers were what I was hoping for but would rather have an odd number and have no one repeat the same game/station.