# What are the different ways to distribute students into breakout rooms?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

I have attended an online university meet & greet session, which got me curious about thinking what were the possible ways to distribute students into breakout rooms. The idea is that all students attend an online meeting, from which they get shuffled into breakout rooms where they get to meet each other. After the 10 minutes are over they get moved to a new breakout room and so on... until the time is over

This brought this question to me (with some assumed constraint)

What are all the possibilities that we can distribute n students into r breakout rooms WITH the constraint that we minimize the number of times a student is in the same breakout room more than once (so each time a student is placed in a new room they are only meeting new faces) AND that there are no more than 7 students per room and no less than 3 students per room?

This is **not** a homework question, i'm rather looking for real-world examples to apply learnings from the classroom.

Edit: Please feel free to make any assumptions (for example: about the number of rooms or number of times required to shuffle students into the room)

Comment: You haven't mentioned the number of times that students shuffle into a room.

Comment: see if this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385806/networking-event-rotation

Comment: @Favst It's flexible to decide on that number. I originally assumed that this needs to be part of the solution